# How to call a method every time a property is changed through two-way binding

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

I've an angular application, with the following component code

```
export class AppComponent {

  length: number = 200;
  width: number = 150;
  height: number = 100;
  margin: number = 5;
  fingerSize: number = 10;
  thickness: number = 3;

  doSomethingOnChange(){
    //...
  }
}
```

Each property is bound with 2-way binding:

```
<div style="display: flex">
  <div>
    <span>Width</span>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="width" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Length</span>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="length" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Height</span>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="height" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Thickness</span>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="thickness" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Finger size</span>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="fingerSize" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Margin</span>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="margin" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to call my method `doSomethingOnChange()` every time the user make any changes to those values. Is there a way?

I tried to implement the [onChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) interface but the method was still not called on updates. Any idea of what I'm missing?

Comment: You could try with [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) to do a cleaner thing

Comment: @Elidor00 I do use it most of the time, but since it's a form that I can "submit", I've no validation rules, it seemed to be  too much for what I needed, but yeah, it seems in the end it's cleaner

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="width" (change)="doSomethingOnChange($event)" />` ?

or you could use ReactiveFormsModule by creating a [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) and subscribe the form.
For example,

```
myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    width: new FormControl(this.width, [Validators.required]),
    height: new FormControl(this.height, [Validators.required]),
    ..........
  });
```

`this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(v => { doSomethingOnChange() })`

```
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input type="number" formControlName="width"/>
    ......
</div>
```

Comment: I thought it was a bit the big guns for nothing, but in the end I feel it's kind of the cleaner way to do it, even if I don't want the user to be able to submit the form.

Is there a way to have the value updated on each change(on keypress, not on focus changes?)

Comment: Angular provides keyup event binding, this could be ```<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="length" (keyup)="keyUp($event)"  />``` and ```keyUp(e:any){ console.log(e.target.value) }```

Answer (score 1):

You can use getter/setter to intercept interactions with given fields. ngOnChanges will be called only for mutations of `@Input/@Output` fields

```
export class AppComponent {

  _length: number = 200;
  get length(){
     doSomethingOnLengthRead();
     return this._length;
  }
  set length(v:number){
     doSomethingOnLengthWrite(v);
     this._length=v;
  }
}
```

alot of boilerplate will be generated, but will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just add  (change)="doSomethingOnChange()" to each input.

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="width" (change)="doSomethingOnChange()" />
```

This will fire the event once the value is committed to the model.

OR , if you want to trigger every time user interacts with the input, you could do instead:

```
<input type="number" [ngModel]="width" (ngModelChange)="doSomethingOnChange()"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "committed to the model" ? Does it means once the form loose focus?

Comment: as it was written there, as the  INPUT loses focus. could have used something like keypress/keydown to mimic (ngModelChange) behavior, Conversely , for ngModelCHange you could have controlled when you want to fire it with ngModelOptions.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to add `(ngModelChange)="doSomethingOnChange($event)"` to your form element. From [the NgModel docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel):

> Event emitter for producing the ngModelChange event after the view model updates.

Your HTML might then look something like:

```
<div style="display: flex">
  <div>
    <span>Width</span>
    <input type="number" [ngModel]="width" (ngModelChange)="handleWidthChange($event)" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Length</span>
    <input type="number" [ngModel]="length" (ngModelChange)="handleLengthChange($event)" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Height</span>
    <input type="number" [ngModel]="height" (ngModelChange)="handleHeightChange($event)" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Thickness</span>
    <input type="number" [ngModel]="thickness" (ngModelChange)="handleThicknessChange($event)" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Finger size</span>
    <input type="number" [ngModel]="fingerSize" (ngModelChange)="handleFingerSizeChange($event)" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Margin</span>
    <input type="number" [ngModel]="margin" (ngModelChange)="handleMarginChange($event)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll just want to make sure that you are setting the value that is then bound back to your form element. Ex:

```
handleWidthChange(event: any) {
  this.width = event;
}
```

Should result in less boilerplate code than the getter/setter method if using template-driven forms.

Comment: But this implies to have 6 methods that updates the property, isn't that the same boilerplate?

Comment: @J4N Compared with using the getter/setter approach, it requires half the amount of methods to update the properties - 6 instead of 12 (getters + setters). If you were looking to limit the amount of methods used, you could create a `handleChange()` that accepts the `$event` as well as the name of the property that is being changed (`handleChange($event, 'width')`), then add a switch statement in that method that dictates which property to update with the value provided.